# Deploy root certificate to Firefox on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, trusted-root-certificates

I want to know how to deploy a root certificates for the Firefox on Mac OS X. I've found some solutions to do it on Windows and it works like a charm. Now I want to do the same on Mac OS X. we have many clients with this OS and it would be very
wasteful if we have to do it manually on the clients. I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to make any user inputs an the machine.

I've found the OS X alternative to `certutil` -> `security`
but with security I can only add the certificate to the keychain.
It seems like that Firefox don't use the keyhain to check the certificates.

How can I add the certificate to the user specific cert-store?

Comment: Just for those stumbling here via a search and trying to add a root CA to the system store on macOS:
````sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain" ca.crt```` will do the trick from the command line

Answer (score 7):

Starting Firefox 63, you can set **security.enterprise_roots.enabled** to **true** (via about:config) to configure Firefox to use OS Keychain for trusted root certificates store.

This will not be back-ported to Firefox 60 ESR.

For additional information, see this bug report [1300420](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1300420)

Comment: This works, is easy and above all CLEAN

Answer (score 5):

Firefox uses its own certificate-storage. So if you add a certificate to one firefox you should be able to determine the changed file(s) inside the users firefox-profile and deploy them to every other user. Alternatively find the main certificate store inside the Firefox.app and replace that with a certificate store containing your root cert.

**UPDATE**

The file you are interested in is `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/[profile-id]/cert8.db`. Have a look at https://sadique.io/blog/2012/06/05/managing-security-certificates-from-the-console-on-windows-mac-os-x-and-linux/ for more informations. Scroll down to the **Firefox**-section.

The downside on that approach is that the user might loose already added root-certificates.

Comment: That link is now dead.

Comment: @JouniK.Seppänen - Thanks for informing: I've updated the link ;)

Comment: Hello @JouniK.Seppänen, I am the author of the blog post. I moved my blog's address and the article is currently at http://sdqali.in/blog/2012/06/05/managing-security-certificates-from-the-console---on-windows-mac-os-x-and-linux/

Comment: Easier is the answer from @cantonese, super easy, clean and makes firefox use the system certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Spend a half day, however, solve the problem!

The link in the previous answer to the deleted blog record suggests to replace cert8.db with premade one - it is very bad idea as user will lose all already accepted certificates.

Certificates have to be added to the cert8.db with use of NSS Tool - certutil.

And I successfully managed to build the latest version of [NSS Tool 3.23](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_23_RTM/) on Mac OS - El Capitan
You can [download archive from my DropBox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15715229/Software/certutil_mac.zip)

Hope it would help to others

Comment: FYI: `brew` now has it

Comment: `brew` has certutil under the `nss` package